# "Emunah Ramah" (Exalted Faith) by Avraham ibn Daud (Raavad I) in Artscroll's "The Rishonim"

Tags: artscroll

Can anyone who has a copy of Artscroll's "The Rishonim" look in it and check if they mention Avraham ibn Daud's (Raavad I) "Emunah Ramah" (Exalted Faith) in the Artscroll book's entry on that Rabbi?  And if so, what do they write about that sefer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a whole lot, but here it is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man.....

Comment: Artscroll seems to have meant “...Motot’s translation, entitled Emunah Neseah, exited [*only*] in manuscript.” Though Norbert Samuelson utilized Motot’s translation in the former’s Hebrew/English edition of ‘The Exalted Faith’.